# is Typhim Vi a live vaccine?

Tags: vaccine

I have contacted 2 local pharmacies, one informed me Typhim Vi is a live vaccine, while the other one told me it is not. I have searched online and was not able to find a conclusive answer.

CDC only says "[One is an inactivated (killed) vaccine and the other is a live, attenuated (weakened) vaccine.](https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/hcp/vis/vis-statements/typhoid.html)" It doesn't specify which is which.

Please help and thank you in advance!

Comment: The CDC also states that the live one is by mouth and the inactivated one is by injection (intramuscular). The one you're referring to is intramuscular as on the CDC site [here](https://www.cdc.gov/typhoid-fever/typhoid-vaccination.html) - just needed to hit the right page there for the details. :)

Comment: Since @JiminyCricket. has pretty much answered the question with that link, would you care to delete your question? If not, you need to [edit] the question to add that link as prior research, and it would be nice if you would fix the URL to be a functioning link.

Comment: Hello, Jiminy Cricket, thank you so much for your help. I hope I have fixed the URL, Carey Gregory ...

Comment: You can also search for the data sheet for the vaccine name - it'll give you the package insert (e.g. for [Typhim Vi](https://www.fda.gov/media/75993/download)) with a whole bunch of information, but you want the *dosage and administration* section, which describes route of administration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the not so subtle hinting of Carey Gregory...

There are a couple of methods of determining the specifics of vaccines.

The authoritative method is to use the package insert. This tells you all about the vaccine including the formulation, administration, contraindications, side effects, etc. Package inserts can be obtained from your doctor when you go to get the vaccination or found online. For the USA, [immunize.org](https://www.immunize.org/official-guidance/fda/pkg-inserts/) has a repository of vaccine inserts from the FDA, though you can also get them directly off the FDA. The Typhim Vi one is available as a PDF from the FDA [here](https://www.fda.gov/media/75993/download). The *Dosage and Administration* section is the part you want for route of administration. The initial *Description* section describes what makes up the vaccine - in the case of Typhim Vi it is a polysaccharide purified from the bacterium. This process (unsurprisingly) kills the bacterium, so this is an inactivated vaccine.

A warning that the package inserts can be a little information heavy to read and contain a lot of medical information that might be hard to read if you have no medical/science background.

With thanks to @JiminyCricket:

The CDC in the USA also has information on vaccination for many diseases by many different vaccines, including the [Typhim Vi](https://www.cdc.gov/typhoid-fever/typhoid-vaccination.html) information in a condensed form.

Comment: lol... sorry, but thanks :-)

Comment: @CareyGregory No worries; I assumed the Q would be closed for lack of research.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your detailed explanations!